# Unable to extend postgresql database with timescaledb

Tags: postgresql-10, timescaledb, patroni

I have created a PostgreSQL cluster with 3 nodes using Patroni.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Postgresql-10 and Timescaledb 1.4.2.

In `postgresql.conf` file I have included `shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'`

When extend the `postresql` with `timescaledb` using the command

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
```

it gives the error

> ERROR:  cache lookup failed for function 1

Comment: This suggest some sort of database corruption. Can you check if you have the extension already installed with `select name, installed_version from pg_available_extensions where name = 'timescaledb'`?

Comment: iu_timeseries=# select name, installed_version from pg_available_extensions where name ='timescaledb';
    name     | installed_version 
-------------+-------------------
 timescaledb | 
(1 row)

Comment: i got output like this

Comment: i got output like this it does not show the installed version

Comment: Yes, I got the same. I tried this locally both with and without the `shared_preload_libraries` and it worked in both cases. If some columns had the wrong type, it could cause this error, so are you using matching versions of PostgreSQL and TimescaleDB?

Answer (score 1):

So, to summarize our discussion on Slack, this is what was the issue. I'm summarizing it here since it can be useful to others that run into a similar problem.

**TD;DR.** You had problems with *all* extensions on this machine, not only TimescaleDB, and the problem turned out to be related to creating new C functions which the extension was doing.

When functions are defined, PostgreSQL takes the part after `LANGUAGE` (in this case `C`) and look for a language validator in `pg_languages`. The code for this is in `CreateFunction` in the file `functioncmds.c`.

In your case `pg_languages` contained:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_languages;
lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 |
sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 |
plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         13005 |     13006 |        13007 |
c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |            1 |
(4 rows)
```

From the table above, OID for the language validator (which is our culprit) is 1.

Once that is done, PostgreSQL will call the validator with the function to be defined and allow the validator to check that the function is correctly defined. This is done in `ProcedureCreate` in the file `pg_proc.c`.

It proceeds by looking up the OID of the function in the `pg_proc` table, which in your case contained:

```
SELECT oid, proname FROM pg_proc WHERE oid = 1;
oid | proname
-----+---------
(0 rows)
```

So, no procedure for the language validator is found and it generates the error here (this is inside `fmgr_info_cxt_security` in `fmgr.c`):

```c
    /* Otherwise we need the pg_proc entry */
    procedureTuple = SearchSysCache1(PROCOID, ObjectIdGetDatum(functionId));
    if (!HeapTupleIsValid(procedureTuple))
        elog(ERROR, "cache lookup failed for function %u", functionId);
    procedureStruct = (Form_pg_proc) GETSTRUCT(procedureTuple);
```

It is possible to fix this by looking up the correct language validator to use. All the built-in validators are named `fmgr_<lang>_validator` so we can find them using:

```
SELECT oid, proname FROM pg_proc WHERE proname LIKE '%fmgr%validator%';
 oid  |         proname         
------+-------------------------
 2246 | fmgr_internal_validator
 2247 | fmgr_c_validator
 2248 | fmgr_sql_validator
(3 rows)
```

So, this query will update the `lanvalidator` column to use the right validator.

```sql
UPDATE pg_languages
   SET lanvalidator = (SELECT oid FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'fmgr_c_validator')
 WHERE lanname = 'c'
```

Note that this explains why you get the error, but not why `pg_languages` contained the wrong OID for the `lanvalidator` column. We hypothesized that it could something that happened during a failover since you had a few promotions happen, but ultimately, it is pure guessing.

Comment: There is a longer discussion about this issue in [psql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/b7082510-b2a1-acbe-dc79-d4492eccacc4%40gmail.com)

Comment: You saved my day.